# How to find out which "unit" is logging to journalctl

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I am working with usbmount and have finally got it working. One of the reasons it took me so long to get it working is that I thought the newest version of it (built from source) was not correctly mounting my drives as I could not see the mount command in the logs. I was using:

```
journalctl -u systemd-udevd.service -f
```

to view the logs based on [this](https://www.shellhacks.com/raspberry-pi-mount-usb-drive-automatically/) blog post. The later version that I am now using though seems to be it's own service and does not log under that unit.

If I run just `journalctl  -f` then I do see the logs that I am interested in:

```
Apr 23 06:51:35 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting usbmount@dev-sda.service...
Apr 23 06:51:35 raspberrypi usbmount[925]: loaded usbmount configurations
Apr 23 06:51:35 raspberrypi usbmount[927]: trying to acquire lock /var/run/usbmount/.mount.lock
Apr 23 06:51:35 raspberrypi usbmount[930]: acquired lock /var/run/usbmount/.mount.lock
Apr 23 06:51:35 raspberrypi usbmount[949]: /dev/sda contains filesystem type vfat
Apr 23 06:51:35 raspberrypi usbmount[952]: mountpoint /media/usb0 is available for /dev/sda
Apr 23 06:51:35 raspberrypi usbmount[953]: executing command: mount -tvfat -osync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime /dev/sda /media/usb0
```

but I get loads of other stuff as well (everythign in fact!). I have tried:

```
 $ journalctl -u usbmount@.service -f
-- Journal begins at Mon 2022-04-04 13:05:58 BST. --
```

but there are no logs. I have tried `systemctl list-unit-files --all` but there is nothing listed in there that looks like it might be the "unit" that I need to view usbmount logs. IN fact in the logs above you can see it say `Starting usbmount@dev-sda.service` so I am confused as to why this doesn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the `@` in `usbmount@.service` indicates it's [a template unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Description). You can have `usbmount@foo.service`, `usbmount@1000.service`, etc., each of which instantiates the template with a parameter (`foo`, `1000`, respectively). The names of these instantiated units are `usbmount@foo.service`, `usbmount@1000.service` respectively, and not the plain `usbmount@service`. So the name to be used with `journalctl` would be `usbmount@foo.service`, `usbmount@1000.service` respectively, and in your case, `usbmount@dev-sda.service`.

To just show logs from any `usbmount` service you can use a pattern in the unit name:

```
journalctl -u 'usbmount*'
```

That said, you can tweak `journalctl` output to see more details. For example, there's `--output=with-unit`, which will show the exact unit name:

```
% journalctl --output with-unit _PID=703 -n 1
Sat 2022-04-23 06:01:27 UTC muru gdm.service[703]: GLib: Source ID 163 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

So the unit that produced this log entry is `gdm.service`.

You can also use `--output=verbose` to see everything there is to know about a log entry. Example:

```
% journalctl --output verbose _PID=703 -n 1
Sat 2021-11-13 04:20:53.377000 UTC [s=6edbe8a0f4d644ac88a82448282c6f5b;i=2c4cb;b=977a8e5bf1c04b458502c8a9230477dc;m=b04611bd2;t=5dd4c12dfd4b7;x=e25d8723d4bd6c3c]
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=system.slice
    _BOOT_ID=977a8e5bf1c04b458502c8a9230477dc
    _MACHINE_ID=06f3f1ec925e4a81834eee9c5c7da4fc
    _HOSTNAME=muru
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _TRANSPORT=syslog
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=1ffffffffff
    PRIORITY=3
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=1
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=gdm
    _PID=703
    _COMM=gdm
    _EXE=/usr/bin/gdm
    _CMDLINE=/usr/bin/gdm
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/system.slice/gdm.service
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=gdm.service
    _SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID=ee4611230c6b443d9eb5b362250d19b3
    SYSLOG_TIMESTAMP=Apr 23 15:01:27 
    MESSAGE=GLib: Source ID 163 was not found when attempting to remove it
    SYSLOG_RAW=<11>Apr 23 15:01:27 gdm: GLib: Source ID 163 was not found when attempting to remove it
    _SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1650693687464817
```

You can see in this case that the command for PID 703 is `gdm` (`_COMM=gdm`) and the unit is `gdm.service` (`_SYSTEMD_UNIT=gdm.service`).

There's also JSON output for easier machine parsing.